# How to create labels, y_axis in percentage, and grid lines

Tags: python, plot, cmd, histogram

I'm trying to plot cumulative distribution for a dataset, I'm stuck at creating or changing y-axis to percentage and adding axis labels.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


st_cum = st_new[['sys_mod_count']]
#sort values per column
sorted_values = st_cum.apply(lambda x: x.sort_values())

#plot with matplotlib
#dimensions per variable.

for col in sorted_values.columns: 
    y = np.linspace(0.0,100.0, len(sorted_values[col].dropna()))    
    plt.plot(sorted_values[col].dropna(), y)
```

[image: graph plot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add the following lines:

```
plt.xlabel("X")
plt.ylabel("Y") 
plt.grid(True) #Grid plotting
plt.axis('equal') #Space is equal in both axis
plt.show()
```

You can find more information here: [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/index.html)

In order to show the percentage, just write the percentage symbol in the ylabel

Comment: Thank you for the input. I want to change values on y-axis to percentage

Comment: In that case, you must divide the y values by 100. By doing for example: y = y/100 before plotting them.